# How to identify all the cyclic groups within a symmetric group Sn?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

There might be many cyclic groups within a symmetric group Sn. Is there any explicit result as how to find the total number of them?

Although, it could be shown that any permutation is decomposable into cyclic permutations.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "all the single sub-group"? Are you asking how to count all the subgroups of the subgroups of the permutation group $S_n$ on $n$ letters, or how to enumerate all the subgroups, or what?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the single subroup?"  Is it "every single subgroup" that is, "all the subgroups?"  Or is a "single subgroup" a special kind of subgroup, in which case, I wish you'd give the definition, because I've never heard of it.

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? Like polynomial in $n$? Exponential in $n$? Polynomial in $n!$?

Comment: Also there are (at least) $n$ copies of $S_{n-1}$ in $S_n$.

Comment: @Benjamin, I know, that's why I was asking if you consider polynomial in $n!$ efficient or not, since a brute force method would require at least exponential in $n!$ time (although even if you checked each subset, not sure how one efficiently one could check if it were a simple group).